# Specify Java command line options after jar execution

Tags: java, command-line

In an effort to make my app more OSX friendly, I am trying to set the dock name of my program to something like `MyApp` instead of a fully qualified class name (the default), such as `myproject.mypackage.mysubpackage.myclass`. Obviously, the first is much more appealing.

To do this, I use the OSX `-Xdock:name` command as a command line option when executing my .jar file. So to execute it, the command might look something like `java -Xdock:name=MyApp -jar /mypath/myjar.jar`. This works perfectly and sets the .jar's dock name to `MyApp`. But the issue is that this .jar will never be executed via command line and will be a double-clicked runnable .jar with a GUI display.

The only way I have thought of to set this command line option programmatically is to have a second class execute the class that actually starts the program. So something like this:

```
public class AppStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cmd = "java -Xdock:name=MyApp -cp myproject/mypackage/AppBuilder";
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec(cmd);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            //Display error message
        }
    }
}


public class AppBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Start actual program and build GUI display
    }
}
```

So here, `AppStarter` sets the command line options for `AppBuilder`, which when executed, has the dock name `MyApp`. The problem I see with this is that it is very tightly coupled. If for some reason the command line is inaccessible on the device or some IOException keeps getting thrown, literally nothing will happen with the program and it will be dead. There would be no way for the average computer user to recover from this.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to perhaps set these command line options after the .jar has already started executing. The old way to programmatically set the app's name has been ineffective for several OSX updates, so I'm stuck with only this command line option. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Once the `java` command is executed, the command line arguments are parsed and set for the running JVM. You cannot change it any more.**

This is usually handled by execution scripts (bash, etc.). If you cannot use them, you can use your approach, but the biggest disadvantage is that it will be running in a separate process.